# Fire events when key is released VBA

Tags: vba, excel, keyup

I have this code to detect when *Enter* is pressed

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" _
(ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
   Const VK_RETURN As Integer = &HD
```

And I use this function in a macro like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) < 0 Then Enter = True Else Enter = False
   If Enter = True Then
       Call IncreaseValue
   End If
End Sub
```

This however is called multiple times when the *Enter* key is held down.
Is there a way to only call this function once every time the enter key is pressed?

Additional info just in case:
Why I need it is because I have a dataentry sheet, which works as a form - every time the enter key is pressed, it increases a cell value by 1, which is used to lookup values. But holding down enter will skip through records.

Comment: Then tell people not to hold the Enter key. Or why do you need to hold it down? Any reason?  It is a normal behavior in Windows that if you hold a key it starts repeating the signal after a short period. I think it's worth that you re-think your approach. For me it is not really clear what you want to achieve. Can you give more details?

Comment: I agree with @Peh. This seems like a user issue. However, you could use something like `Application.DataEntryMode` to "disable keyboard" after the initial keypress. Fraught with danger though!

Comment: There is no particular reason to hold down the enter - just when going over entered things I noticed some have been skipped. So I guess they fall into deep thinking while holding down the enter key for 2 seconds or something.

Just to make it "fool-proof" you know, some extra measures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there's! All you need is to track `Enter` key [toggling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) (note return values).

The main idea behind that is to track the low-order bit (*toggle/untoggle*), and whenever it changes and the high-order bit is 1 (*pressed*) - we're free to increase what we desire.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static StatePreservedResponse As Long
    Dim StateResponse As Long

    StateResponse = GetKeyState(VK_RETURN)

    If StateResponse < 0 And StateResponse <> StatePreservedResponse Then
        Call IncreaseValue
    End If

    StatePreservedResponse = StateResponse
End Sub
```